# Porting from Java 8 to 11: com.sun.xml.internal.messaging.saaj.soap.SAAJMetaFactoryImpl not found, how to change implementation?

Tags: java, jax-ws, java-11, saaj

I'm trying to port an old Java 8 webapp containing JAX-WS based webservices to Java 11 and Tomcat 9 on Windows 10. Note that this app is not using Maven or any other dependency management and there are reasons against a conversion.

After adding the jaxws-rt library, I'm getting the following error:

```
java.lang.Error: javax.xml.soap.SOAPException: Unable to create SAAJ meta-factoryProvider com.sun.xml.internal.messaging.saaj.soap.SAAJMetaFactoryImpl not found
        at com.sun.xml.ws.api.SOAPVersion.<init>(SOAPVersion.java:193)
        at com.sun.xml.ws.api.SOAPVersion.<clinit>(SOAPVersion.java:91)
        at com.sun.xml.ws.api.BindingID.<clinit>(BindingID.java:342)
        at com.sun.xml.ws.spi.ProviderImpl.createEndpoint(ProviderImpl.java:107)
        at javax.xml.ws.Endpoint.create(Endpoint.java:162)
        at javax.xml.ws.Endpoint.create(Endpoint.java:116)
        ...
```

The `internal` infix already shouldn't be there, as this seems to be a Java 8 package stripped from Java 11. I've tried the following:

- adding the libs `saaj-api-1.3.5.jar` and `saaj-impl-1.5.1.jar`
- starting Tomcat with `-Djavax.xml.soap.SAAJMetaFactory=com.sun.xml.messaging.saaj.soap.SAAJMetaFactoryImpl`, which point to a location in `saaj-impl-1.5.1.jar`
- creating a file `<MyWebapp>/META-INF/services/javax.xml.soap.SAAJMetaFactory` with contents `com.sun.xml.messaging.saaj.soap.SAAJMetaFactoryImpl` (which btw. is also contained in `saaj-impl-1.5.1.jar`)

all to no avail. It keeps asking for that internal implementation which isn't there anymore.

How do I tell Java to use the correct implementation and, if possible, how can I find out who is causing this implementation to show up anyway?

Answer (score -1):

This worked for me.

I needed to add following dependencies.

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.sun.xml.ws</groupId>
    <artifactId>rt</artifactId>
    <version>2.3.2</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.sun.xml.ws</groupId>
    <artifactId>jaxws-rt</artifactId>
    <version>2.3.2</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.sun.xml.ws</groupId>
    <artifactId>jaxws-ri</artifactId>
    <version>2.3.2</version>
    <type>pom</type>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.sun.xml.messaging.saaj</groupId>
    <artifactId>saaj-impl</artifactId>
    <version>1.5.1</version>
</dependency>
```

I also needed to set property.

```
System.setProperty("javax.xml.soap.MetaFactory","com.sun.xml.messaging.saaj.soap.SAAJMetaFactoryImpl");
```